# docker-compose displaying all services not the one defined in docker-compose.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I am executing docker-compose like below

```
docker-compose --compatibility -f docker-compose.yml up --scale es01=0 --scale elasticsearch-mapping-init=0 --scale analytics-db=0 

docker-compose --compatibility -f docker-compose.app.yml up --scale autocomplete-service=0
```

After this when I am executing the below command it is displaying all services not just the ones defined in `docker-compose.app.yml`

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.app.yml ps --services
```

Output

```
backoffice-db
booking-ending-db
booking-engine-service
master-service
objectstore-service
profile-service
sagev2-service
supplier-service
directory-db
```

docker-compose.app.yml has only the below services

```
version: '3'
    services: 
        master-service:
            image: master:latest
            network_mode: "host"
            restart: always
            environment:
                - SPOTNANA_ENV_TYPE=dev
                - IS_E2E=true
            ports:
                - "8080:8080"     # master-service
            deploy:
                resources:
                    limits:
                        memory: 1862M
    
        supplier-service:
            image: supplier:latest
            network_mode: "host"
            restart: always
            environment:
                - SPOTNANA_ENV_TYPE=dev
                - IS_E2E=true
            ports:
                - "6565:6565"     # supplier-service
            deploy:
                resources:
                    limits:
                        memory: 2960M
    
        booking-engine-service:
            image: bengine:latest
            network_mode: "host"
            restart: always
            environment:
                - SPOTNANA_ENV_TYPE=dev
                - IS_E2E=true
            ports:
                - "6569:6569"     # booking-engine-service
            deploy:
                resources:
                    limits:
                        memory: 2462M
```

- Docker Compose version v2.6.0
- aws/codebuild/standard:6.0

Can someone let me know why `docker-compose -f docker-compose.app.yml ps --services` not listing the services defined in `docker-compose.app.yml` only?

**NOTE** - I started seeing this problem only after moving to `aws/codebuild/standard` image 6.0 from 4.0. In image 6.0 `docker-compose` is upgraded to 2.6.0 from 1.26.0 in image 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been discussed in [docker community](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-displaying-all-services-not-the-one-defined-in-docker-compose-yml/133157). It is a bug in docker-compose v2.6.0 and is fixed in v2.13.0. For now I have used the below workaround or the workaround discussed in docker community can also be used.

It is working if I also add the project parameter, `-p` to `docker-compose`

```
docker-compose --compatibility -f docker-compose.yml -p infra up --scale es01=0 --scale elasticsearch-mapping-init=0 --scale analytics-db=0 

docker-compose --compatibility -f docker-compose.app.yml -p app up --scale autocomplete-service=0
```

Then pass `-p` in the `docker-compose ps` like below

```
docker-compose -p app ps --services
```

An [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/issues/588) is also opened in AWS to upgrade the `docker-compose` in the codebuild image.